# Give different color to the each colums using Asp.net chart control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, charts

Give different colors to the colums using asp.net chart control. Adding column manually can give different color but when adding column using Dynamically/data-source not able to give different color.
This is the code of my chart

```
 <asp:Chart ID="chartPerformance" runat="server" BackColor="OldLace"
                IsMapEnabled="False" Width="600px" Height="350px" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" 
                            Palette="Chocolate">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="ReportName" YValueMembers="TimeTaken"
                        IsValueShownAsLabel="true" YValuesPerPoint="6">
                        <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="false" />
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        <AxisY>
                            <MajorGrid Enabled="False" />
                        </AxisY>
                        <AxisX>
                            <MajorGrid Enabled="False" />
                        </AxisX>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
```

Assigning data using datatable.

```
chartPerformance.DataSource = dt;
chartPerformance.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/MSWinWebChart/thread/983b9b8e-56f5-4a02-8bfa-d793879e50bd

```
chartPerformance.Series[0].Points[0].Color = Color.AntiqueWhite;
chartPerformance.Series[0].Points[1].Color = Color.Blue;
chartPerformance.Series[0].Points[2].Color = Color.Red;
```